# Application Context Using Dagger?

Tags: java, android, singleton, dagger

I'm trying to pull Context in to a class using Dagger, here's what I have and the errors that ensue:

```
@Module(injects = { MyApp.class, TransportModule.class }, library = true, includes = { TransportModule.class })
public class AppModule {

    private final MyApp remoteApp;

    public AppModule(MyApp remoteApp) {
        this.remoteApp = remoteApp;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return remoteApp;
    }

}
```

**Application Class:**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        instance = this;
        super.onCreate();

        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());
        objectGraph.inject(this);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        private List<Object> getModules() {
        return Arrays.<Object>asList(new AppModule(this));
    }

    public ObjectGraph createScopedGraph(Object... modules) {
        return objectGraph.plus(modules);
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public static LoQooApp getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

}
```

**DeviceInfo.java:**

```
public class DeviceInfo {
    static LoQooApp baseApp;
    @Inject
    static Context mContext;

    public DeviceInfo() {

    }

    public static boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                Log.v(TAG, Integer.toString(resultCode));
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG + "NOPE", "This device is not supported.");
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

LogCat Error:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke 
     virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager 
     android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object   reference at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvai lable(Unknown Source)


     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke 
     virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager 
     android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object   
     reference
     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvai lable(Unknown Source)
```

There are whole bunch of methods in DeviceInfo that need context they all fail.
How do I bring context into that Class via Dagger or even without Dagger?

Comment: You don't want to keep a static reference to the `Context`. Either provide it as a parameter in your methods, or create a `DeviceInfo` instance which takes the `Context` in its constructor. Then you can inject the `DeviceInfo` instance into your classes using it.

Comment: Inject DeviceInfo in where? Other classes that use its methods like a BaseActivity?

Answer (score 1):

Static injections can be done ([How to inject into static classes using Dagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656967/how-to-inject-into-static-classes-using-dagger)), but this should be the exception. You should rather make both the method and the field not static.

So, DeviceInfo looks like

```
@Inject public DeviceInfo(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
public boolean checkPlayServices() { //not static
```

Then, DeviceInfo is injected

```
public class MyApp {
    @Inject DeviceInfo deviceInfo;
```

which is set by objectGraph.inject(this); in onCreate.

If you need DeviceInfo in activites, you also call inject in onCreate

```
MyApp app = (MyApp) getApplication();
app.getObjectGraph().inject(this);
```

You also need to add the activity to the injects part of the AppModule.

Comment: can you give any example code because Dagger/DI is already a maze to me. I need to "see" what you are describing. ty